# LocationMatch Regex Behavior

Tags: regex, apache, locationmatch

I am trying to set a bunch of url-based rules in Apache with LocationMatch and the regex seems to behave in a way I do not understand.
I tried looking up the documentation but it isnt very clear to me WRT to my issue... nor are the other question/answers around the interwebs.

Here is my Location directive and a generic example of the structure of my LocationMatch directives:

```
<Location />
    Header set X-Intelligence "CatchAll"
</Location>

<LocationMatch "\.(pdf)$">
    Header set X-Intelligence "pdf1"
</LocationMatch>
```

- These directives are all inside a virtual host with ssl.
- I am not using any other Location or LocationMatch directives anywhere else in the configs.
- The LocationMatch directives all come after my CatchAll Location directive.
- Everything works normally when I use just the `<Location />` directive alone.

I have noticed some differences between the regex used here and the regex I have experience with..

- Using start/end slashes doesn't seem to work.
- Using ending modifier tags like /i /g do not work.
- Other behavioral differences given below

---

I have tried many different things but here are some examples of my results:

**1.**

```
<LocationMatch "(?i)\.(pdf)$">
    Header set X-Intelligence "pdf1"
</LocationMatch>
```

- The above seems to match all .pdf and .PDF extension URLs.

However:

```
<LocationMatch "\.(pdf)$">
    Header set X-Intelligence "pdf1"
</LocationMatch>
```

- Does not match any .pdf extension URLs.
- .pdf do not get caught by the CatchAll (displays 404 not found).
- .PDF (capitals) do get caught by the CatchAll.

.
**2. Not similarly:**

```
<LocationMatch "\.(docx?)$">
    Header set X-Intelligence "doc2"
</LocationMatch>
```

- The above matches my .docx URLs.

However:

```
<LocationMatch "\.(doc)$">
    Header set X-Intelligence "doc2"
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "\.(docx)$">
    Header set X-Intelligence "doc22"
</LocationMatch>
```

- The above does not match .docx URLs.
- Does not get caught by the CatchAll (404 not found).
- I have tried rearranging the order and still gives same results.

---

Not sure what is going on but the behavior is totally not what I expect.
Anyone have any ideas on what I could be doing wrong or what I am not understanding?

Open to any suggestions to make this question better. Thanks.

Comment: I can't replicate with Apache 2.2, I suspect something else is interfering. I tried `(?i)\.(docx?)$` as well as `(?i)\.docx?$`. Since you aren't capturing you can get rid of `(` and `)`. This is not really a programming question and is probably better suited to [sf]

Comment: hmm ok thanks for trying to replicate.